Linking to a cross-compiled static library using cross-linker not working
I am using the same cross-toolchain on two different build hosts to cross-compile and link to a C library, respectively.
Host A is a Ubuntu 16.04 container with arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi tools used to cross-compile and generate a static library, mylib.a.
Host B is a CentOS container with arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi tools used to cross-compile other stuff and then link to the static lib (mylib.a copied in from Host A) generated on Host A.
When linking on Host B, this error message is raised:
    error adding symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I've confirmed that mylib.a does contain the index header (see What does the Linux 'ar' generated index file look like in a .a file?)
I tried extracting the .o's from the .a, copying them into Host B, and arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-ar on Host B. But no difference.
Is the issue incompatabilty between the build hosts?
Or could it maybe be that I am not specifying a target to arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-ar (among supported targets: elf32-littlearm elf32-bigarm elf32-little elf32-big plugin srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex)?
Thanks
EDIT:
Running /app/tools/xilinx/vivado2016.4/SDK/2016.4/gnu/arm/lin/bin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-nm on mylib.a on either Host A or B gives:
vtss_phy_ts_util.c.o: File format not recognized

for each of the .o files in the archive.

Are you passing the s option to ar?

@LHLaurini Yes, passing -s to ar

Please [edit] your question to add detailed information on both tool chains like version numbers and source, please. Also all command lines to build can be helpful.
